Is $\sf P\neq NP\cap coNP$ relative to random oracle still open?
In 1981 Bennett and Gill have established the first set of separation results relative to a random oracle. In particular, for almost all oracles $A$, we have $\mathsf{P}^A\neq\mathsf{NP}^A\neq\mathsf{coNP}^A$. Furthermore, given oracle access to a random permutation $\pi$, we have $\mathsf{P}^\pi\neq\mathsf{NP}^\pi\cap\mathsf{coNP}^\pi$. However, the question of whether $\mathsf{P}^A$ equals $\mathsf{NP}^A\cap\mathsf{coNP}^A$ relative to random oracle is left unanswered.
I have found a handful of papers which mention this problem, but the most recent one I found being Vereshchagin's NP-sets are Co-NP-immune relative to a random oracle, from 1995. I was curious if there has been any more recent work on this problem.

Are there any more recent works which shed any light on this question?


It is indeed still open, and for good reason.
A combinatorial conjecture of Rudich and Impagliazzo implies that $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}\cap\mathsf{coNP}$ relative to a random oracle implies $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$.
Further, this combinatorial conjecture is true. This was proven in a lovely paper by Kahn, Saks, and Smyth in 1999.
Edit: My mistake, this paper is for $\mathsf{NP}\cap\mathsf{coNP}\subseteq\mathsf{AvgP}$ under a random oracle, not $\mathsf{P}$!

Is this right? I can't access the full paper, but the abstract says that P = NP implies only that $\mathsf{NP\cap coNP\subseteq i{.}o{.}AvgP}$ relative to a random oracle, rather than $\mathsf{NP\cap coNP=P}$ relative to a random oracle.

Having glimpsed at the paper and others referenced, it indeed doesn't seem to claim anything about P = NP $\cap$ coNP itself relative to oracles, although they do suggest that it may be strengthened to NP $\cap$ coNP being contained in AvgP relative to random oracle, the class of problems with a polytime algorithm which is correct on positive fraction of instances. While interesting, still a far cry from P itself.

@EmilJeřábek Ah thank you, you are right! It is for $\mathsf{AvgP}$, not $\mathsf{P}$.
